# waitForServer issue

Tags: microcontroller, ros-control, ros-kinetic, follow-joint-trajectory, action-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

System: Virtualbox VM Linux: Ubuntu 16.04 ROS: Kinetic

I am working on manipulator jogging using the [jog_control](https://github.com/tork-a/jog_control) package. I've posted this on the github [issues](https://github.com/tork-a/jog_control/issues/33) page already but I thought I'd try here as well.

I am trying to set this package up to use the [Kuka KR16](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental) arm but am having some problems with the controllers which is giving me the following warning:

```
Waiting for arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory server...
```

as it is waiting on the `TrajClient`'s `waitForServer` method.

I have been trying to replicate the contents of the launch files in the example given in the [readme](https://github.com/tork-a/jog_control#ur3-and-ur5gazebo-and-moveit) for the UR5 arm but am still coming up short. I am not sure how the `follow_joint_trajectory` server is being created in the UR5 packages and I have not been able to find a tutorial or guide that explains the `follow_joint_trajectory` controller.

I don't want to make the post too long so I will only include my launch files for now and if need be, I can include other info later as required.

This first launch file, `kr16.launch`, launches Gazebo, Rviz, MoveIt! and loads the arm and controllers.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <arg name="limited" default="false"  doc="If true, limits joint range [-PI, PI] on all joints." />
  <arg name="paused" default="false" doc="Starts gazebo in paused mode" />
  <arg name="gui" default="false" doc="Starts gazebo gui" />
  <arg name="sim" default="false" doc="If true, use the simulated joint controllers"/>
  <arg name="use_moveit" default="true"/>
  <arg name="use_rviz" default="true"/>
  
  <!-- startup simulated world -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" default="worlds/empty.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- send robot urdf to param server -->
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find kuka_kr16_support)/urdf/kr16_2.xacro'" />

  <!-- push robot_description to factory and spawn robot in gazebo -->
  <node name="spawn_gazebo_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param robot_description -model robot -z 0.0" respawn="false" output="screen" />

  <!-- spawn the joint_state_controller and joint_trajectory_controller-->
  <rosparam file="$(find kr16_moveit_config)/config/ros_controllers.yaml" command="load"/>
  <node name="arm_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" ns="kuka_kr16_2" args="joint_state_controller arm_controller" respawn="false" output="screen"/>

  <!-- Remap joint_states -->
  <remap from="/joint_states" to="/kuka_kr16_2/joint_states"/>

  <!-- Robot state publisher -->
  <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher">
    <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
    <param name="tf_prefix" type="string" value="" />

  </node>

  <!-- Launch rviz -->
  <node if="$(arg use_rviz)"
    name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz"
    args="-d $(find jog_launch)/launch/jog.rviz"/>


  <!-- Remap follow_joint_trajectory -->
  <remap if="$(arg sim)" from="/follow_joint_trajectory" to="/kuka_kr16_2/arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory"/>

  <!-- Launch MoveIt! -->
  <include if="$(arg use_moveit)"
       file="$(find kr16_moveit_config)/launch/move_group.launch"/>

</launch>
```

This file gives the following notable fatal error when launched:

```
[FATAL] [1565103003.906290212]: Parameter '~moveit_controller_manager' not specified. This is needed to identify the plugin to use for interacting with controllers. No paths can be executed.
```

The 2nd file, kr16_jog.launch, is responsible for launching the actual jogging node:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <!-- Remap joint_states -->
  <remap from="/joint_states" to="/kuka_kr16_2/joint_states"/>

  <!-- Remap follow_joint_trajectory -->
  <remap from="/follow_joint_trajectory" to="/kuka_kr16_2/arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory"/>

  <!-- Launch jogging node -->
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find jog_launch)/config/kr16_jog.yaml"/>
  <node name="jog_frame_node" pkg="jog_controller" type="jog_frame_node" output="screen">
    <param name="use_action" value="true"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

which gives the warning as stated at the beginning of this post.

Any help with this issue is much appreciated. I might have left out some useful info so please let me know if any further info is required.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330103/waitforserver-issue/) by [mt](https://answers.ros.org/users/42562/mt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2019-08-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-06**:\

> I've posted this on the github issues page already but I thought I'd try here as well.

please do not cross-post questions like this.

Give the developers/maintainers of the package a chance to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After trawlling through various tutorials and vidoes on ROS control, I found a solution to the problem. It was a problem of namespaces betwen Gazebo and ROS.

I went back and did the MoveIt! config setup again for the robot arm. I then removed all references to namespaces. So no namespace in the URDF for Gazebo, removed the namespace from the MoveIt! generated controller files and any namespaces in launch files.

The following is based on my understanding of ROS control so may not be totally accurate. So I then figured out that in the error message:

```
Waiting for arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory server...
```

The `arm_controller` refers to the actual controller and `follow_joint_trajectory` is the action server (really not sure how this works). So in my `controllers.yaml` file, I changed the following:

Previous:

```
joint_state_controller:
  type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
  publish_rate: 50
controller_list:
  - name: "arm_controller"
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:
      - joint_a1
      - joint_a2
      - joint_a3
      - joint_a4
      - joint_a5
      - joint_a6
arm_position_controller:
  type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  joints:
    - joint_a1
    - joint_a2
    - joint_a3
    - joint_a4
    - joint_a5
    - joint_a6
  ...(controller gains etc...)
```

Now:

```
joint_state_controller:
  type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
  publish_rate: 50
controller_list:
  - **name: ""**
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:
      - joint_a1
      - joint_a2
      - joint_a3
      - joint_a4
      - joint_a5
      - joint_a6
arm_position_controller:
  type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  joints:
    - joint_a1
    - joint_a2
    - joint_a3
    - joint_a4
    - joint_a5
    - joint_a6
```

Removing the `name` field from `controller_list` meant that ROS would now be looking for an action server on the `/follow_joint_trajectory` topic. I then remapped the topic `/follow_joint_trajectory` to `[controller_name]/follow_joint_trajectory` so in my case I added the follwing to my launch file:

```
 <!-- Remap follow_joint_trajectory -->
  <remap if="$(arg sim)" from="/follow_joint_trajectory" to="/arm_position_controller/follow_joint_trajectory"/>
```

This led to the controller being found and loaded correctly.

I hope this is of help to others and I would appreciate anyone more knowlegable improving the answer and my understanding of ROS control.

---

Originally posted by [mt](https://answers.ros.org/users/42562/mt/) with karma: 61 on 2019-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0